# How to install WCF service using WiX installer?

Tags: wcf, wix, hosting

How do I create WiX installer for WCF service in this case?

1. At the start user choose hosting: self-hosting, in IIS, in system service.
2. Depending on his selection I need to install one of 3 different sets of files, do specific custom actions etc.

How to implement this in one installer?

PS. I have made installer for installation of IIS-hosting WCF.

But how to do 3-in-one?

Answer (score 2):

Best bet is to have separate Features in the installer. Under each feature you can have the components (one component per dll please) that make up each hosting type. Then you can also have any custom actions be [conditional on component action state](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa368012%28VS.85%29.aspx)

If you haven't already separate all of the service logic into its own assembly that can be referenced by the host projects (Web Services, Win Service, etc). So in the grossly simplified list of output files you'd have:

- Common.dll
- IIS.svc file
- IIShost.dll
- Windows Service.exe
- Self host.exe?

It would be possible to have all of their target directories be the same one, but it probably makes sense to have a directory per hosting type. In that case Common.dll would need to be copied to each folder and would need a separate wix component for each location.

The default UI using the feature selection tree would work, but I do not believe you can force only selecting a single feature. If you want to go with a more customized feature selection you should [start with reading this](http://www.joyofsetup.com/2007/05/30/feature-conditions-and-ui/)